# Connected subsets of a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I have to prove the following result:

Suppose $X$ is a metric space, $Z$ is a metric subspace of $X$ and $S \subset Z$ Then $S$ is a connected subset of $X$ if, and only if,$S$ is a connected subset of $Z$.

My Attempt:

I think the topology of $S$ should be the same whether it is viewed as a subset of $X$ or of $Z$.

So whether $S$ is connected or not should not really depend on either $X$ or $Z$.

So if it is connected it should be connected in both.

Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, the topology it inherits from $X$ and $Z$ are the same.  Just use the definition of inherited topology and that $S$ is contained in $Z$.

Comment: I think the topology of S should be the same whether it is viewed as a subset of X or of Z-false. $Z$ must be open in $X$ to be true

Comment: You have to use the subspace topology,where $A\subset Z$ is open in $Z$ if there exists an open set $G\subset X:A=Z\cap G$

Comment: @Dimitris: The fact that $S\subseteq Z\subseteq X$ ensures that if $Z$ has the subspace topology inherited from $X$, then $S$ inherits the same topology from $Z$ and from $X$. No conditions on $Z$ are required; in particular, $Z$ need not be open in $X$.

Comment: Right.I got confused from the fact that the family $T$={$G:G\subset   Z$ and $G$ open in $X$} is a topology iff $Z$ is open in $X$

Answer (score 0):

Whether your reasoning is sufficient depends on the definition of a connected set you were given. Some of them explicitly refer to the topology of ambient space, for example:

> A subset $S\subset X$ is connected if there do **not** exist two subsets $A,B\subseteq X$ such that $S\subseteq A\cup B$, $A\cap S\ne\varnothing$, $B\cap S\ne\varnothing$, $A\cap \overline{B}=\varnothing$, and $\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing$.

Here the closures refer to closure in $X$, and thus on the formal level, connectedness involves the topology of $X$, not just of $S$. It then takes a proof to show that connectedness is independent of the ambient space.